# ggplot2 Change color of specific bar in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the color of bar and condition is score below 60.
Where do I set my condition,and color it? Thanks for helping.

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(Student = sample(state.name, 10), score = sample(1:100, 10, replace=T))

ggplot(df, aes(Student, score)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  labs(x = "Student_name" , y = "math_score")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an extra column which tells your condition using `case_when` and assign that column to your `fill` in `geom_bar` with `scale_fill_identity` like this:

```r
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(Student = sample(state.name, 10), score = sample(1:100, 10, replace=T))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(
    score < 60 ~ "red",
    TRUE ~ "Grey"
  )) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Student, score)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = color), stat='identity') +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  labs(x = "Student_name" , y = "math_score")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I couldn’t have done it better myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without creating an extra column you may want to use

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(Student = sample(state.name, 10), score = sample(1:100, 10, replace=T))


ggplot(df, aes(Student, score)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = score < 60), stat='identity')+
  scale_fill_manual(guide = "none", breaks = c(FALSE, TRUE), values=c("dodgerblue", "firebrick1")) +  
  labs(x = "Student_name" , y = "math_score")
```

resulting in

[image]

Comment: Your color is so dazzling!!! Thanks  for your answer!